Screen zoomed in a little on raspberry pi 4
I just had a look around but could not find a solution to my problem.
I'm currently configuring a raspberry pi 4 with Ubuntu installed as some kind of kiosk device with some custom software on it (just an electron app the launches a web view basically). However once I start the pi, the screen is always slightly zoomed in. It cuts of the side a bit which is really annoying. You also can't really see if the device is connected to the internet because it also cuts off the top bar. It also detects the display as 1920x1080p device
This is what I have tried so far

Updating drivers
Reset the zoom level in settings
Reset my display
Use another display (funny enough on a 1440p monitor it works fine, on another 1080p display there's the same issue again)

Any ideas what this could cause?
Many thanks in advance
Bendix :)


Are you using a TV?; as what your picture shows is somewhat common on TVs when fed images from a PC as TV monitors tend to overscan

Yeah in this image it's a tv, the display where it's supposed to work on is a professional NEC 40" display, don't know the exact model tho. Any way to fix this?

Where a monitor is overscanning, the usual fix is via the monitor itself (ie. turn off that feature; some TV & consumer grade monitors have limited options, but a professional monitor intended for computer screens will have that function).  You usually find you need to reverse the setting when you reconnect a DVD or other media device

I'll try that, thanks :)
